# I used nvdidia-docker to install mysql5.7 using the nvidia/cuda image in nvidia-docker. I found that the mysql service could not be started

Tags: docker

> docker-ce version 18.06
> nvidia-docker version :2.0.3
>
> ---Error log---
>
> 2018-07-23T02:44:29.671833Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /home/.mysql
>
> 2018-07-23T02:44:29.828378Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
>
> 2018-07-23T02:44:29.829058Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 14371 ...
> 2018-07-23T02:44:30.143178Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180723  2:44:30 mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
>
> 2018-07-23T02:44:30.143214Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
>
> 2018-07-23T02:44:30.143482Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
>
> 2018-07-23T02:44:30.178359Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
>
> 2018-07-23T02:44:32.112395Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /home/.mysql/mysqld.pid ended

Comment: Please post the error message as text so it can be found by others facing the same problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not very well edited text information ;